# How to implement State Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on the .NET framework. I have implemented the singleton pattern and the State pattern. My code is BankAccount which has auto-implemented property i.e. AccountStateID. now I want to implement a method called ChangeState in my BankAccount class which will keep calling statechangecheck which is found in my AccountState class and all the subclasses. Here is my code for the StatechangeCheck method

```cs
public override void stateChangeCheck(BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    if (bankAccount.Balance > this.UpperLimit)
    {
        GoldState.GetInstance();
    }
    else if (bankAccount.Balance < this.UpperLimit)
    {
        BronzeState.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

The same code will be applied to the other subclasses.
The changeState method will ensure the account is in the correct state when a bankAccount balance is modified. I want to use a While loop for this.

Comment: Not related to your question, but is your intention that if `bankAccount.Balance == this.UpperLimit` nothing should happen?

Comment: You are telling us what you want to do. What is preventing you from it? Where is the actual problem? I see no question.

Comment: The statechangecheck method and the ChangeState methods are different I have already implemented the StateChangeCheck method but now I want to call it in the changeState but before doing that I need to retriave an account state from the databse I also want to keep track of the new stateID and the old one after i called StateChangeCheck

Comment: I would expect that the result of GoldState.GetInstance() needs to go somewhere. But then I don't know the actual implementation